# getDirectory(Class<ExifSubIFDDirectory>) is undefined

Tags: java, metadata, exif, metadata-extractor

I'm trying to get specific EXIF (and later IPTC) Tags with the "metadata-extractor-2.8.0.jar" library from [here](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor).

For the first simple usage, I wanted to try the code from the "getting started" for the Raw Values.
But I ran in a problem, you can see in the attached picture.

[Picture](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) (can't post images yet.)

Add.Info: I can read all TAGs with for each loops. So the libs are working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Looks like the sample hasn't been updated after the 2.8.0 release. Did you try

```
getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifSubIFDDirectory.class);
```

That fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out too, just some hours ago, and was about to post it. :)